# How to set variables on the fly from the console?

Tags: javascript, console

I would like to set variables on the fly using the console.

My code is wrapped like this:

```
( function () {

var debug = true;

// code here

} () )
```

I want to change `debug` on the fly using the console.

Should I move `debug` out of the self executing wrapper and pass it in using the global import?

Should I give the anonymous function a name, and set it using the "name spaced" name?

I have not used the console too much, but I assume it is made for things like this.

How is this usually done? What is best practice?

Comment: "Should I move debug out of the self executing wrapper and pass it in using the global import?" – pretty much. I'd just make it an explicit global, namespace it if you're feeling antsy about the idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a namespace with minimal effort as follows:

```
(function (foo) {
    foo.debug = true;
}(FOO = FOO || {}));

FOO.debug = false;
```

I would go with this type of solution over using an explicit global because it isn't really more cumbersome and with variable names like `debug` there's a chance you might have a conflict.. even if you're working with code that is 100% yours.

Comment: Does FOO have to be passed in?

Comment: It does not have to be passed in, but it allows you to forego defining it outside. Also, with more complicated namespaces/subnamespaces you can pass in `FOO.subNS` and refer to it as just `subNS` within your function. I feel like that makes it a lot less tedious.